# Is it required to remove all ppas for distro upgrades?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kubuntu, ppa

I want to upgrade my Kubuntu install to Kubuntu 22.04 LTS as soon as it's released.

As a general approach (not only for the transition to 22.04): is it required to remove all ppas before upgrading? If yes: Can I save a list of all ppas to readd them later? And will all software be still there after the upgrade (flatpaks, snaps, apt apps and apps from ppas)?

Comment: `And will all software be still there after the upgrade (flatpaks, snaps, apt apps and apps from ppas)?` -- For snaps and flatpaks, yes. For apt - yes unless some software has some dependency issues (which should not happen if you only use official sources, and it probably won't happen if you are using software from PPA). But it is recommended that you disable the PPAs before upgrading (but usually there is no need to uninstall the software installed from the PPA).

Comment: Afaik, `do-release-upgrade` will save your repositories in `.list.save` files. I guess it will take a couple of days to weeks for most `ppa`s to provide packages for 22.04. Some won't ever do that. There is no guarantee that software from `ppa` is surviving the upgrade. Best is to ppa-purge all `ppa`s, then upgrade, then reinstall the `ppa`s that you need.

Comment: PPAs are disabled prior to *release-upgrade*, nothing further gets done. Third party software is often a reason the *release-upgrade* (*QA & CI testing of upgrades includes only Ubuntu repository software*) though will fail; so you may get told this with a message to `ppa-purge` them if 3rd party packages prevent upgrade; having them survive (ie. only disabled) makes this easier (eg. Oibaf graphics drivers prevent *release-upgrade* as one example; once ppa-purged the *release-upgrade* can occur, then user can add the 3rd party drivers back if required).

Comment: So is it possible to disable the ppas and enable them later again? I would like if I don't have to remove them and then readd them at a later point. And if I remove a ppa, will the software I installed from it also be deleted? I don't really know much abouht this stuff yet and I don't use linux for a really long time.

Comment: Disabling a PPA is just adding a "#" at the start of the line, ie. turning the line into a comment.. That is dead easy to reverse..  If you were on *impish* and *release-upgraded* to *jammy* and had PPAs disabled though; I would expect those lines to still have *impish* in them, ie. the codename is not touched during the "disable" (they're just commented out via addition of "#" at the start of the line).  Note: this is subject to change any time anytime as the [ubuntu-release-upgrader tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) changes

Comment: guiverc so the ubuntu-release-upgrader tool should change some time later. So won't be the issue with the ppas anymore? And I actually don't know the file which stores the ppas. Could you tell me what file that is?