# Ubuntu release upgrade: Will installed deb packages be kept?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, deb

It's kind of an addition to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396840/is-it-required-to-remove-all-ppas-for-distro-upgrades#comment2418862_1396840) question I asked. I would want to know if all of my installed .deb packages wont get removed. I have some like Discord.

Comment: Upgrades can require the replacement of packages, which can require/cause the removal of other packages to meet requirements. Your question though is *broad* & vague without limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have manually installed deb packages, they won't get removed -- usually.

But there are exceptions.

A release upgrade or even just `apt full-upgrade` removes old packages if needed to perform the upgrade of packages to their latest versions. Also, new packages might get installed which could conflict with manually-installed ones.

In this case, you get asked if you want to accept the removal of these packages. You could look for a compatible package or accept that your system cannot be upgraded.

There is no universal solution, you have to look at it on a case-by-case basis.